# python - globals to access the variables between __main__ and class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I wanted to share a value between the **main** and a class. How to do it?

I am calling a class from **main**. This class executes a function and if it fails wanted to proceed with other functions. At the end, wanted to pass the status 'False' if any of the function fails and 'True' if all the functions have executed successfully.

I wanted to pass the status back to **main**. I tried globals()[status] = True in class
and 
def **name = '__main**':
after calling the class methods.
 if globals()[status]:
   print 'all methods executed successfully.'

Is it possible to share a variable between class and **main**? The globals didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Typically you'd `return` values from functions and pass them to other functions as parameters…!?

Comment: hard to debug without actual code but what happens if you change `__main` to `__main__`? Also comparing two values requires `==` instead `=`

Answer (score 0):

There is your class:

```
class testClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 1

    def funA(self):
        try:
            print("success_#1")
        except:
            self.state = 0

    def funB(self):
        try:
            print("success_#2")
        except:
            self.state = 0

    def funC(self):
        try:
            print("success_#3")
        except:
            self.state = 0
```

There is your main:

```
test = testClass()

while(1):
    test.funA()
    test.funB()
    test.funC()

    if(test.state == 0):
        print("error")
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

globals()['dirCopyFailed'] = False worked. 
I was missing the single quote.